# restoring a Replicated table in clickhouse from S3 backup

Tags: clickhouse

my current set up is 3 replicated nodes managed by zookeper (ch 23.3)
I am trying to back up the tables i have on CH to s3 by doing the following:

table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test2 on cluster 'x'(
id UInt64,
  updated_at DateTime DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at_date Date DEFAULT toDate(updated_at)
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/test2', '{replica}')
ORDER BY id;
```

backup:

```
BACKUP TABLE db.test2 on cluster 'x' to S3('https://backup/test2-base', '', '')
```

when I run this restore command I get the following error:

```
 restore TABLE db.test2 AS test2 on cluster 'x' from S3('https://backup/test2-base', '', '')
```

Error:

```
DB::Exception: Got error from chi%2Dclickhouse%2Dch%2Dcluster%2D0%2D1:9000. DB::Exception: Replica /clickhouse/tables/0/test2/replicas/chi-clickhouse-x-0-1 already exists: While creating table default.test2. (REPLICA_ALREADY_EXISTS)
```

I tried to detach the table but i face the same issue, i tried to rename the table as well but with no luck:

```
 restore TABLE db.test2 AS test2_recovered on cluster 'x' from S3('https://backup/test2-base', '', '')
```

how to delete this path? and is it stored in CH server or in Zookeeper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chatted with the Eng and Support teams about this. A few answers:

- The path is stored in keeper
- Using {uuid} in the path would allow this to be stored and not conflict: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/sre/keeper/clickhouse-keeper#configuring-clickhouse-keeper-with-unique-paths

The system can often take some time (up to 8 minutes?) to garbage collect old entries (could use the ZooKeeper SYNC command to force this action). Not using explicit paths by the table name can be effective, or using {uuid} in the path, or as mentioned above use unique paths in the keeper config

Comment: One other option is to first CREATE TABLE manually and then RESTORE with setting allow_different_table_def=true as described here https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/48846#issuecomment-1514873142

Comment: using {UUID} in the table path fixed the issue indeed, many thanks!